# graduate degrees in Applied Mathematics.

Tags: soft-question, education, advice

I always thought of the general preliminary for a graduate program in applied math as Calculus, Real analysis, Complex variables, DE, introductory Linear algebra, probability and statistics etc. But I read somewhere undergrads looking into graduate degrees in applied math should also take a course in discrete mathematics, and theory of equations, is this necessary?

Note: This is not so much a requirement as building up a strong background for research to come. I guess in this sense, I am asking how discrete mathematics and equation theory relate to applied math.

Comment: Which country?  Which institution?  Requirements and course content differ significantly (e.g., you are probably expected to have at least two or three courses on fluid dynamics for DAMTP, Cambridge but probably none of that in certain institutions in the US where "applied math" means statistics).

Comment: What is theory of equations? Perhaps some form of abstract algebra?